# Parallax plugin not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing a background with parallax by angularjs but I am having some problems.

These are the files: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j7r3s33Y3GcTyH2Fop9K?p=preview)

The directive that's used is "parallaxBackground".

Once applied to the section

`<section-parallax background parallax-ratio =" 0.5 "class =" container-fluid parallax_style1 "style =" background: url (http://test.simonepignatelli.com/img/parallax1.jpg); ">`

The code does not run, the section concerned are those with the second and third image.

Suggestions?

Comment: What module are you using specifically? There are (at least) two different angular modules called angular-parallax.js

Comment: I used this https://github.com/brettdonohoo/angular-parallax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parallax directive has a bunch of logic bound to window `scroll` and `touchmove` events, but these never fire because your window element isn't scrolling: it's your `.slideTop` element. If you set it to `overflow: hidden`, you'll see that your page doesn't scroll at all. As a result, the `setPosition` method in your parallax directive never fires.

Comment: Great , I restored the element as suggested and the parallax working properly but now the problem is on the animation when the page is loaded . Suggestions ?

Comment: Sounds like the subject of a new question! :D